# What is the regs() equivalent in Elixir?

Tags: erlang, elixir

Just like we use `regs().` in the Erlang shell to list all the processes running on BEAM is their an equivalent of this in Elixir or iex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`regs()` is a function defined in the [`c` module](https://erlang.org/doc/man/c.html) which is imported into the Erlang shell by default. In Elixir, you can call it using `:c.regs()`.

```
iex(1)> :c.regs()

** Registered procs on node nonode@nohost **
Name                  Pid          Initial Call                      Reds Msgs
'Elixir.IEx.Broker'   <0.91.0>     'Elixir.IEx.Broker':init/           34    0
'Elixir.IEx.Config'   <0.90.0>     'Elixir.IEx.Config':handl           80    0
'Elixir.IEx.Pry'      <0.92.0>     'Elixir.IEx.Pry':init/1             36    0
'Elixir.IEx.Superviso <0.89.0>     supervisor:'Elixir.Superv          416    0
...
```

Comment: thanks, it worked, I didn't know about the c module